# Boost and Varnish together in Presflow

Tags: 6, caching, proxies

One of my client drupal 6 site boost installed and working properly. Now they need to integrate varnish to the site. For that the site is upgraded to pressflow. The varnish is installed in server, and [Varnish 6.x-1.1](http://drupal.org/project/varnish) installed in site.  The varnish running status got in admin/settings/varnish page.

varnish version: 2.1
server: ubuntu

[image]

When boost is disabled i got varnish working properly, i used [isvarnishworking.com](http://isvarnishworking.com) to check the varnish status.

**My problem is to make work boost and varnish together**. For doing so, i followed this article [Boosted Varnish - High Performance Caching made easy](http://www.trellon.com/content/blog/boosted-varnish-high-performance-caching-made-easy). I updated the default.vcl with the changes mentioned in this article, but it not caching.

It showing age header is less than 1

[image]

the other details are

[image]

In admin/settings/performance i set Caching mode: external and Page cache maximum age: 1 day

Any help to make work boost and varnish together is greatly appreciated

Comment: Why would you want both Boost and Varnish? Isn't it enough to just run Varnish itself for caching?

Comment: @Anoop Joseph Did you find the solution ? Pls. help me by sharing.